# How to detect orientation changes and change layout?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Lets say that I have a grid with 2 rows, 2 columns and many controls inside each cell.

When the application is changed to snap mode, I meant 1/3 of the screen I would like the application to be only, one Column, 2 rows and show only some controls  I would decide.

What kind of control do I have for this?

thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should make use of the VisualStateManager in xaml, for a full xaml solution:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OrientationStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Full"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Fill"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped"/>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Create StoryBoards for each VisualState and hide/show elements in your xaml. Microsoft examples use the same solution.

--

**Update**

I searched the net and found the proper states, an example is behind this link: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx#adapting_to_different_layouts).

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
     <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

The states reflect the [ApplicationViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewstate) enum. Even more information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj129458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer more?, with your help I could get this link, http://www.markermetro.com/2011/11/technical/windows-8-metro-style-apps-layout-and-orientation-management-with-xaml/, so it means that I have to write a different layout for each visual state, and rebind the data on each orientation change to the correct controls depending on the state?

Comment: Yes! That would indeed be the nicest, xaml only, solution afaik. You could with some clever storyboards reuse some of your elements, but you would mostly have to create different layouts. If you do it might be wise to shift them to separate UserControls or Views and include those.

Comment: Sorry, I was a little bit narrow minded. Microsoft created a base Page class that supports these VisualStates. I updated my post with a more useable example...

Answer (score 10):

Using [DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.orientationchanged.aspx) event (as suggested by @Jan K.) may not  be exactly what you are looking for, considering the remarks section to this event:

> The **DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged** event occurs only when orientation of the display or monitor changes and not necessarily when the orientation of your app changes. To determine the orientation of your app for layout purposes, use the [ApplicationView.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.value.aspx) property.

but since [ApplicationView.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.value.aspx) probably will be abandoned after **Windows 8.1** release MS suggest to use **ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()** instead:

> ApplicationView static methods may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1 Preview. Instead, use [ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getforcurrentview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) to get an instance of ApplicationView.

So for now I've end up with that code (have a kind of dynamic view and can't pre-design everything in XAML via VisualStateManager, unfortunately):

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        ApplicationView currentView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

        if (currentView.Orientation == ApplicationViewOrientation.Landscape)
        {
            // when args.Size.Width > args.Size.Height
        }
        else if (currentView.Orientation == ApplicationViewOrientation.Portrait)
        {
            // when args.Size.Width < args.Size.Height
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Have a look on the [`DisplayProperties.OrientationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.display.displayproperties.orientationchanged.aspx)-Event. When it fires you can modify your grid and rearrange your controls.