# change layout based on orientation detect in xaml Windows app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I am trying to alter my views based on landscape and portrait orientation.

I tried code from couple of places, eg:

1. [How to detect orientation changes and change layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975706/how-to-detect-orientation-changes-and-change-layout)
2. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2064993-e4a9-4a58-8498-ef03ed9403f4/how-to-set-grid-row-property-in-visualstatemanager-in-windows8-app?forum=winappswithcsharp

but it does not work for me. Not sure what I am doing wrong.? I am testing it from a Simulator.

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="18*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid/>
<Grid Grid.Row=1/>
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="14*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PageTotals" />

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PageDetails" />

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PageTotals"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PageTotals"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PageDetails"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Column)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PageDetails"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.RowSpan)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I am targeting Windows 8.1 (windows app)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic triggers for `VisualStates` was something introduced with the `LayoutAwarePage` in Windows 8. However with Windows 8.1, the notion of `Snapped` screen got removed and the guidance was to design your app for 320px (setting in manifest) or 500px (default) as the minimum size. The automatic triggers on orientation changes were also **removed**.

There are however samples of developers who tried to reproduce the Windows 8 behavior, like [this post from Jeremy Likness](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2013/08/handling-windows-8-orientations-in.html). You can still write/use code similar to his implementation on the existing 8.1 API's to test the orientation and if your app is full screen and then go to the desired state yourself with `VisualStateManager.GoToState`.

```
private static void SetLayout(Control control)
{
    var orientation = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Orientation;
    string newMode;

    if (orientation == ApplicationViewOrientation.Landscape)
    {
        newMode = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreen ? "FullScreenLandscape" : "Filled";
    }
    else
    {
        newMode = Window.Current.Bounds.Width <= 500 ? "Snapped" : "FullScreenPortrait";
    }

    if (newMode == GetLastOrientation(control))
    {
        return;
    }

    VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, newMode, true);
    SetLastOrientation(control, newMode);
}
```

Source: [Jeremy's post](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2013/08/handling-windows-8-orientations-in.html).

Comment: Is there a way do the same from style using story board ?

Comment: All styles changes stay in your storyboard. It's only the switching between the states that used to be in the `LayoutAwarePage` that you have to do yourself now.