# Preventing commandbar from going into landscape mode

Tags: c#, mobile, uwp

I'm making an app, my first UWP app, I already spent hours looking for this. I need the commandbar to keep in portrait mode while all the rest of the application goes to landscape mode. I need something like this:

[in portrait mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7fVj.png)

[And in landscape mode, see the bar didn't moved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf6rp.png)

here is my code so far:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsSticky="True" Name="cmdBar_ed">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="newBtn" Label="" Width="30" Click="newFile">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/test.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="newBtn1" Label="" Width="30" Click="newFile">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/test.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="newBtn2" Label="" Width="30" Click="newFile">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/test.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="newBtn3" Label="" Width="30" Click="newFile">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/test.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="newBtn4" Label="" Width="30" Click="newFile">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/test.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
            <AppBarButton Name="btnTab" Label="" Width="30" Click="insertTab">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/btnIcon/Tab.png"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="btn_save" Icon="Save" Label="Save" Click="save"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="btn_saveAs" Icon="Save" Label="Save As" Click="saveAs"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="btnClose" Icon="Cancel" Label="Close File" Click="close" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Also, another Strange thing is that when the on screen Keyboard is activated, this bar moves with it to stay on top of the on screen keyboard and not in a a fixed position. how would I do it to fix?

Comment: Are you sure you are developing a UWP? This looks like a Windows Phone 8.1 application to me because in UWP apps there are no rounded glyphs around AppBar icons.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is a UWP application, I'm using my Lumia 435(Upgraded to windows 10 mobile) to run it. and so far works, apart from these issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you put commandbar in `<Page.BottomAppBar/>`, it always changes its position according to current [ApplicationViewOrientation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationvieworientation), you cannot control it.

But if you put it into a panel(e.g, Grid):

```
<Page
x:Class="AppCommandBar.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppCommandBar"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CommandBar Name="cmdBar_ed" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="newBtn" Label="test" Width="30">
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Name="btn_save" Icon="Save" Label="Save"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="btn_saveAs" Icon="Save" Label="Save As"/>
            <AppBarButton Name="btnClose" Icon="Cancel" Label="Close File"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Grid>
```

You could manually set its position by current view's orientation.About how to detect current view's orientation, please check this thread [How to detect orientation changes and change layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975706/how-to-detect-orientation-changes-and-change-layout)

Comment: I looked into that, but I still don't understand how to lock the grid in that position, somehow, this guy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767273/how-to-get-the-device-orientation-changed-event-under-windows-phone) did, see the images?

Comment: @William I meant change the Commandbar's position in Grid(e.g, row,column), not lock the grid's position. You could use `Grid.SetColumn` and `Grid.SetRow` to change Comamndbar's position in different orientation. You need to custom [Commandbar's style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx) to make it show in vertical direction.